# swift textfield bottom line max width

Tags: swift, textfield

I wrote the below code to make the textfield only have bottom line,
the result show as the below image (the bottom line is not long enough to the right edge.)

```
func setBottomBorder() {
    self.borderStyle = .none
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! First try giving the label a backgroundColor (say, red) to see how big the frame is, because I suspect that is the issue here.

Comment: Ensure that didLayoutSubviews are called before the border is calculated.  You can force a layout before setBottomBorder is called. 
You'll have a similar problem if you app supports both landscape and portrait orientation. Whenever the size of the textfield changes, you will need to recalculate the frame of the border.

Comment: Instead of adding `layer` just take a `UIView` at bottom and set its constraints accordingly. `layers` are quite heavy and can disturb the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As per My suggestion instead of progrmatically.

you should set it using **StoryBoard**:

A textfield with Hidden Border.
Below that you can take a label with white background and it is done.

**Note:-** Do not forget to give correct constraints to both so that it looks good

[image]